# MongoDB Aggregation Lookup with Pipeline Doesn't Work

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, aggregation

I have two collections. I am trying to add the documents of Collection 2 to Collection 1, if number 1 and number 2 in Collection 2 is within a certain range as specified in Collection 1. FYI ObjectId in Collection 1 and ObjectId in Collection 2 refer to two different items/products, hence I cannot join the two collections on this id.

Example Document from Collection 1:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('4321'),
 'number1_lb': 61.205672407820025,
 'number1_ub': 61.24170844385606,
 'number2_lb': -149.75074963516136,
 'number2_ub': -149.71471359912533}
```

Example Document from Collection 2:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('1234'),
  'number1': 1.282298,
  'number2': 103.8475}
```

I want the output:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('4321'),
 'number1_lb': 61.205672407820025,
 'number1_ub': 61.24170844385606,
 'number2_lb': -149.75074963516136,
 'number2_ub': -149.71471359912533,
 'recs': [ObjectId('3456'), ObjectId('4567'),...]
```

I thought that a lookup stage with pipeline would work. My code is currently as follows:

```
 {"$lookup":{
        "from": "Collection 2",
        "let":{
            "number1_lb":"$number1_lb",
            "number1_ub":"$number1_ub",
            "number2_lb":"$number2_lb",
            "number2_ub":"$number2_ub"
        },
        "pipeline": [
            {"$match":
             {"$expr":
              {"$and":[
                  {"$gte":["$number1","$$number1_lb"]},
                  {"$gte":["$number2","$$number2_lb"]},
                  {"$lte":["$number1","$$number1_ub"]},
                  {"$lte":["$number2","$$number2_ub"]}
              ]}}}
        ],
        "as": "recs"
    }}
```

But running the above gives me no output. Am I doing something wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran it and it seems to work fine; but I had to tweak your input data in `coll1` as it didn't meet the `$match` the criteria.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import dumps

db = MongoClient()["testdatabase"]
# Data Setup
db.coll1.replace_one({"_id": "4321"}, {"_id": "4321", "number1_lb": -61.205672407820025, "number1_ub": 61.24170844385606, "number2_lb": -149.75074963516136, "number2_ub": 149.71471359912533}, upsert=True)
db.coll2.replace_one({"_id": "1234"}, {"_id": "1234", "number1": 1.282298, "number2": 103.8475}, upsert=True)
# Run the aggregation
results = db.coll1.aggregate([
    {"$lookup": {
        "from": "coll2",
        "let": {
            "number1_lb": "$number1_lb",
            "number1_ub": "$number1_ub",
            "number2_lb": "$number2_lb",
            "number2_ub": "$number2_ub"
        },
        "pipeline": [
            {"$match":
                {"$expr":
                    {"$and": [
                        {"$gte": ["$number1", "$$number1_lb"]},
                        {"$gte": ["$number2", "$$number2_lb"]},
                        {"$lte": ["$number1", "$$number1_ub"]},
                        {"$lte": ["$number2", "$$number2_ub"]}
                    ]}}}
        ],
        "as": "recs"
    }}
])
# pretty up the results
print(dumps(results, indent=4))
```

gives:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "4321",
        "number1_lb": -61.205672407820025,
        "number1_ub": 61.24170844385606,
        "number2_lb": -149.75074963516136,
        "number2_ub": 149.71471359912533,
        "recs": [
            {
                "_id": "1234",
                "number1": 1.282298,
                "number2": 103.8475
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: You are right. My original code was correct, the boundaries were just too small to get anything. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to use a `$lookup` and a `$project` :

```
   {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Collection2",
            localField: [Foreign Field of the Collection1],
            foreignField: [Principal field of the foreign collection here Collection2],
            as: "nameJoint"
            }
    },
    {$project: {

        "newFieldName": 
    }},
```

But to make a joint between 2 document there as to be an commun field between those 2 documents. I am not sure there is one in this situation or I misunderstand it.

(A `$lookup` is bassicaly a SQL joint in noSQL )